# convert string to enum in metaclass and type hints

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I have a lot of Enums and a EnumMeta like

```
class MyEnumMeta(EnumMeta):
    def from_string(cls, s: str) -> Enum:
        return cls[s.upper()]

class A(IntEnum, metaclass=MyEnumMeta):
    ONE = 1
    TWO = 2
    ...

class B(Enum, metaclass=MyEnumMeta):
    BB = auto()
    ...

...
```

If I make the following comparison,

```
A.from_string('TWO') > A.ONE
```

I get the following mypy message:
Unsupported operand types for < ("A" and "Enum")

How can I fix the incompatible types problem? I don't want to define the from_string method in every class and specify the respective class as the return value.

I defined the method in each class and specified the respective class as the return value.

```
class A(IntEnum):
    ONE = 1
    TWO = 2
    ...

    @classmethod
    def from_string(cls, s: str) -> 'A':
        return cls[s.upper()]

class B(Enum):
    BB = auto()

    @classmethod
    def from_string(cls, s: str) -> 'B':
        return cls[s.upper()]
```

Comment: Can you post the whole script that you are running? With your first code block, the statement `A.from_string('TWO') > A.ONE` runs fine for me.

Comment: This isn't about the code working (or not); the question is about an error reported by mypy, a static type checker.

Comment: I'd do smth like [this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=1280044a4b40bb7cb5faa3c7efab71bb). One ignore comment is still necessary, but only on the implementation - much better than on call sites.